# Error in webconfig file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC 4.I am working on a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) which i found on browsing the internet and I am trying to add a model to my application.I have created one and when i try to add a controller it gives me a error message like..

```
Unable to retrive metadata for 'Practice.Models.Customer'.Invalid value for Key 'attachdbfilename'.
```

**MODEL**:

```
public class Customer
 {

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set;}
 }
 public class CustomerDBContext : DbContext
 {
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
 }
```

**Connection string**:

```
   <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-practice-20130320183458;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="CustomerDBContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Customers.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I think there is some problem with ConnectionString but dont know where is it.Please help me solve this problem..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make your enity virtual.

```
public virtual int ID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual int Amount { get; set;}
```